# Slack slash command response body is buffer

Tags: node.js, lambda, netlify

I am trying to use Netlify for my home for my slack slash command. The problem is that the req.body value is `<Buffer 74 6f 6b 65.....`. I am using lambda functions so maybe that is causing the problem

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post("/anime", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
})'
```

What am I missing? I would expect that I would see json of what slack is sending me

Comment: Could you try `console.log(req.body.toString('utf8'));`

Comment: I found the solution. I had to do ```app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));```